# Calculate TVA amount in Transaction FB01

Tags: sap-erp

At the last screen of my Batch Input, normally TVA amount should be calculated, but as shown in screenshot it's not calculated automatically.

[image: The screen shot]

In screenshot:

1. is the amount the must be calculed
2. the reason why the amount is not calculated in supposedly second line 1.

do someone have an solution to calcule it ?

Thank you,

Best Regards,
Yassine